# Drag and Drop interfering with scroll Angular 7 CDK

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 7 app and has angular cdk drag and drop in it to rearrange a list. Drag and drop works fine but it cannot auto scroll the div container. Is there any way to get auto scroll to work without updating the version of angular/cdk as per this link
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13588

My current version of angular/cdk: 7.3.7.

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dggptq-rhbitf

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: maybe this will help :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dggptq

Comment: Thanks Aakash. But the version for @angular/cdk used in your example is 8.1.1. I am looking for a workaround for auto scroll for version of angular/cdk as 7.3.7.

Comment: give a stackblitz, i will check.

Comment: stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dggptq-rhbitf

Comment: find my solution below, no need of custom code was there. also mark it as solution if it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Problem was with Your HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="timePeriods" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let timePeriod of timePeriods" cdkDrag>{{timePeriod}}</div>
</div>
</div>
```

To

```
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="timePeriods" class="example-list container" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let timePeriod of timePeriods" cdkDrag>{{timePeriod}}</div>
</div>
```

Working Stackblitz :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dggptq-fmjjjx

Reason :- for autoscroll to work your scroll should be on cdk drop list, so i removed extra div and applied your container class to cdkdrop list div.

Comment: Though this is working fine in StackBlitz, it is not working the same when in the application. The dependencies used are of the same version. Not sure if I am missing something here.

Comment: can't guess that, since not having access to your application.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
[see this comment](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14098#issuecomment-633679567)